# Mention multiple users

Tags: feature-request, comments, users

I know that in comment the number of mentions (`@user`) is limited to one (in addition to the OP).

But in some cases, as in [How do I prevent one user in particular from accessing my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609194/restricting-a-specific-user-from-accessing-my-home-in-linux/609201#609201), I would like to mention a specific group of users --- for example, a `@close-voters` would be very useful here (and in other Q&A, too).

Is this possible? If not, would be a candidate for asking for a new feature in the main meta site?

Clearly this feature should be limited. For example

- Access "group mentions" only with >2k reputation in general,
- Never allows mention @close_voters or @down_voters on your own question or answer (or maybe with >20k rep?);
- Limit "group mentions" to one of them per question/answer and "sending user" (even if later deleting the comment).

with such limitations it could be a useful instrument and not so suitable for spam or vindictive actions.

Comment: It would be an interesting feature, but I can tell you if I'm voting to close something I read all the comments - and you can ping me in chat and quote the comment.

Comment: I think it's a really good idea that might make our life easier.  The work-around now is: Mark as a favourite question, revisit when closed. edit and leave a big bold comment why this is not a duplicate, vote to re-open.
(re-open votes are quicker to accrue then close votes)  If you want, I can cast the last close vote and then we can start the process of re-opening...

Comment: I like the idea of @ down-voters or @ close-voters . Note - you will still be relying on those users to respond or comment, but getting notice of an update or edit would be nice.

Comment: What is the procedure to submit a new feature proposal?

Comment: @Rmano you pretty much just did, however I think a concerning issue here is that it could be used as a spam / disruptivity vector to attack down voters, close voters, etc.  You also have to consider down voters and upvoters in two contexts: answers, and questions.  I think implementation-wise there's holes in the request.

Comment: @ThomasW. I see. Obviously it should be restricted at, say, 2k reputation or something like that. Will update the question.

Comment: I'd just like to mention that similar stuff have been suggested several times to SE, but they always used to get declined. [example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post) but all of the ones I know of are quite a few years old. Maybe SE might reconsider now.

Comment: Voting is meant to be a private action. Would adding '@down-voters' (etc.) compromise this?

Comment: @minerz029 to the end user, probably not, but you sacrifice some backend stuff, and unless coded right you could 'leak' the data to the clients.  But it would be against the current idea of how highlights work.